# calling a python script from cmake

Tags: python, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a Python script to parse some data from a csv file which lists out all the errors during the runtime of my robot. Now I want to call this Python script from CMake. What is the best way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274105/calling-a-python-script-from-cmake/) by [robo_ninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27502/robo_ninja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-25**:
You really want to "call from CMake" or something like `rosrun your_package your_parser.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In cmake there's something called `execute_process`. Look [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) for documentation.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0